# My loop doesnt run properly in multi-threading

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I try to write a multi-thread program, and meet some problems.

After I run `main.c`, and I get

> i: 0
>   new thread 0
>   new thread 1
>   i: 1
>   i: 1

```
//main.c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void* routine(void* arg)
{
    int id = (intptr_t) arg;
    printf("new thread %d\n", id);
    pthread_exit((void*)(intptr_t) id);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t t[2];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        int ret = pthread_create (&t[i], NULL, &routine,  (void *)(intptr_t) i);
        if(ret != 0) {
            printf("Error: pthread_create() failed\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    int id;
    /////////here
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %d\n",i);
        pthread_join(t[i], (void **)&id);
    }
    /////////here
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

My problems are

- Why the last loop runs thrice?
- If I change `pthread_t t[2]` to `pthread_t t` and create twice, is it possible to call pthread_join twice?

Thanks for your time reading my question.

Comment: http://ideone.com/MTWpZS

Comment: For the second question: No. The second call to `pthread_create` will overwrite the `pthread_t` variable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I got it!! Thanks
@GillBates My compiler's version is `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`, that doesnt run correctly. Is it a problem by case?

Comment: "*that doesnt run correctly.*" its *mostly never* a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @alk Does my problem depend on my OS?

Comment: @GillBates: Just bad luck it looks as if it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add some more debug-logging:

```
int id;
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    printf("i: %d\n",i);
    pthread_join(t[i], (void **)&id);
    printf("id[%d]: %d\n", i, id);
}
```

Re-run and memorize the output.

Then change it to look like this

```
int id;
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    void * pv;   
    printf("i: %d\n",i);
    pthread_join(t[i], &pv); /* Add error checking here! */
    id = (intptr_t) pv;
    printf("id: %d\n", id);
}
```

Re-run and compare to the previous version.

---

As a rule of thumb:

If facing the seemingly need to cast in C (not C++), always think twice, as there are only **very, very, very rare** cases where casting in C is necessary and not only just hiding a programming mistake by silencing the compiler.

Comment: I still think its a little bit weird when `i` change to 0 after calling `pthread_join` in my case. I did not pass `i` to that function. But anyway, thanks for your answer and suggestions.

Comment: @ShawnHuang: `pthread_join()` expects a `void**`, the address of a pointer, it will de-references it to become a `void*` and then assigns to this `void*` a pointer value, which probably is 8byte, The memory referenced by what you passed is an `int`, it's only is 4 byte wide. So some other 4 bytes get overwritten. These 4 bytes most likely belong to the `i`.

Comment: I have never accounted for this side effect while casting. Thanks again for your help.